# URL redirection and rewriting at the same time

Tags: wordpress, apache, url-rewriting, redirect

I have sajjanlamichhane.com website hosted on Amazon EC2. But my actual site is inside sajjanlamichhane.com/wp/. So, I redirect URL but I want to mask the redirect URL. How do I do this?
I have this below

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@sajjanlamichhane.com
ServerName sajjanlamichhane.com
ServerAlias www.sajjanlamichhane.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sajjanlamichhane.com/
ErrorLog /var/www/sajjanlamichhane.com/logs/error.log 
CustomLog /var/www/sajjanlamichhane.com/logs/access.log combined
Redirect http://sajjanlamichhane.com "http://sajjanlamichhane.com/wp/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ http://sajjanlamichhane.com/wp/index.php [R=301,NC,L]
# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule !^wp/ /wp%http://sajjanlamichhane.com [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you solve. Further links to read: 
http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/url-masking.php

```
    Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80> 

     ServerAdmin root@sajjanlamichhane.com
     ServerName sajjanlamichhane.com
     ServerAlias www.sajjanlamichhane.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/sajjanlamichhane.com/
     ErrorLog /var/www/sajjanlamichhane.com/logs/error.log 
     CustomLog /var/www/sajjanlamichhane.com/logs/access.log combined
     Redirect http://sajjanlamichhane.com "http://sajjanlamichhane.com/wp/
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond http://sajjanlamichhane.com/wp/index.php http://sajjanlamichhane.com/wp/index.php$
     RewriteRule .* /wp/index.php [L]



</VirtualHost>
```